# Magento reindexing loses Solr docs

Tags: magento, solr

This is driving me a bit crazy. I'm running Magento EE 1.11.1 with SOLR running. We have a cron that runs every night which reindexes the entire site. Every time it does this, I check the SOLR configuration and the *numDocs* and *maxDocs* values are only a fraction of what should be currently indexed (27000 versus ~90000). **This means that when I do a search on the site, the results are only a fraction of what they should be.**

The only way to get search working properly is to stop SOLR, delete and recreate the /apache-solr/site_name/solr/data folder, restart, and reindex just the Catalog Search index via shell. If I try to run this specific reindex via shell *without* deleting and recreating the data folder, I get only about half of the docs that I should be getting (~51000).

All index files in the data folder are owned by root, and the SOLR jar is running as root. I have all logs set to *warning* but nothing is currently being logged. I manage other sites using Solr and never have this issue - this install however has many attributes (330) and many products (~100,000). Could that be part of the issue? Thanks!

Comment: What has Enterprise support said?

Comment: There are a lot of solr related fixes in 1.12: http://concisedeveloper.com/magento/release-notes-ee1-12/, maybe you see some of those bugs fixed in 1.12.

Comment: @benmarks give us all your ssh/db credentials from live site and we will get back to you...

Comment: The fix entitled "Fixed: Products missing on frontend if SOLR enabled" is kind of scary... Sounds like a lot was fixed in 1.12 regarding SOLR. I've continued to debug and find the root of this problem but no luck so far!

Comment: To all interested, I might have found a solution and I am curious if any of you still have issues. Please check my answer for a possible fix and do comment with any and all problems you still face.

Answer (score 3):

EE1.12 may not be a solution either. We have a client on EE1.12 that is having problems with the SOLR integration. In their case, all attempts to index fail when the indexer accesses custom product attributes.

Nexcess and Magento support have been working on this for over 6 weeks, the current status from Magento support is -

> Unfortunately the patch is still under development, and I'm unable to advise on when our developer will complete it.

Comment: Good to know that I'm not going crazy. Is this in a public facing support ticket anywhere? Good luck.

Comment: No - no public ticket,  this was with Magento EE support.  Yesterday we got a note telling us that the support developer said we were missing some blocks on the search results page.  Now, I don't know how the front facing blocks affect the Magento - SOLRs indexing - but we tried it anyway.  Needless to say, it did not fix the problem.

Comment: @GregC check my answer for a possible fix.

Answer (score 3):

Since the Enterprise_Search module adds a cronjob that runs everyday by default at 3am I've found a better solution than adding a line of code to the file `shell/abstract.php`.

All you need to do is create a small module that adds a certain event to the global namespace instead of admin:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourNamespace_YourModuleName>
             <version>0.0.1</version>
        </YourNamespace_YourModuleName>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <!-- The misspelling (cat-e-logsearch) is correct, you can look it up in the config.xml of the Enterprise_Search module -->
            <catelogsearch_searchable_attributes_load_after>
                <observers>
                    <enterprise_search>
                        <class>enterprise_search/observer</class>
                        <method>storeSearchableAttributes</method>
                    </enterprise_search>
                </observers>
            </catelogsearch_searchable_attributes_load_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Don't forget to activate your module by placing another configuration file at `app/etc/modules/YourNamespace_YourModuleName.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourNamespace_YourModuleName>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Enterprise_Search/>
            </depends>
        </YourNamespace_YourModuleName>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Now you can rebuild the Solr index from the command line by issuing the following command from the Magento root folder (assuming you have shell access, of course):

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to give proper credit: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/290878/#t421155

Comment: Thanks minzwurst - but we are seeing this issue in 1.12.0.2. And in this version, the event has already been moved to the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

After checking for a solution to this for a couple of days (incidentally bumping to this question), I think I have a solution. I tested it and I haven't seen any bugs appearing.

```
# shell/abstract.php @ line 75
public function __construct()
{
    if ($this->_includeMage) {
        require_once $this->_getRootPath() . 'app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Mage.php';
        Mage::app($this->_appCode, $this->_appType);
        Mage::app()->addEventArea('adminhtml');# the magic line
    }

    $this->_applyPhpVariables();
    $this->_parseArgs();
    $this->_construct();
    $this->_validate();
    $this->_showHelp();
}
```

The problem was that `enterprise_search/observer` wasn't loaded so it could fire the `storeSearchableAttributes` method. This lead to various extra data to fail to register.

The only side-effect I can think of, is that now shell **execution will load all admin observers**. This might lead to a decrease in speed, defeating part of the purpose of running from shell. It will not be as slow as the browser, but it will probably be slower than before.

If you have any questions or think I might help in another way, do tell!

Answer (score 1):

Have you spent some time looking at the solr logs while you are running the indexer? We are currently running 1.12 and found several issues with solr even there. We had to troubleshoot when solr would notify us of a bug.

My comments are in my answer here: [Magento 1.12 and Solr 3.6 No proper results and no spell suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667728/magento-1-12-and-solr-3-6-no-proper-results-and-no-spell-suggestions)

I would assume this advice would apply to 1.11 but you may have to modify it slightly.
Open ./app/code/core/Enterprise/Search/Model/Adapter/Abstract.php
and find prepareDocsPerStore.

You can monitor and log the documents that are being sent to solr as a sanity check. So you could for instance do something quick and dirty below $docs[] = $doc;
like:

$solr_log_file = '/mnt/tmp/'.date('Y-m-d',time()).'/'.$storeId.'-'.$productId.'-solr.txt';
file_put_contents($solr_log_file, var_export($doc, true));
Warning: I may have some syntax errors as I just hammered this out.

doing a var_export of $productIndexData before and after this line also proved illuminating:
$productIndexData = $this->_prepareIndexProductData($productIndexData, $productId, $storeId);

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have find another solution for this issue in my case i made a small script with following code

```
ini_set("memory_limit","1000M");
require_once "app/Mage.php";
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$observer = Mage::getModel('enterprise_search/observer');
$observer->storeSearchableAttributes();
```

with the name solrindex.php and run this in browser like mydomain/solrindex.php and then i reindex catalogsearch from admin and this works for me.

Comment: Thanks - but that's not working for ee 1.12.0.2 -- "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getEvent() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Enterprise/Search/Model/Observer.php on line 171"  I'll dig around and see what I can find