# Incomplete SOLR document with Magento

Tags: magento, search, solr

For some reason I have SOLR documents that have not all the required attributes from Magento. For example 'visibility' is missing, as wel as the categories. This causes the articles not to show up on a search.

While investigating, I found that sometimes it helps if I edit and then save the product with the incomplete document. I see the document is being updated in SOLR. Then, after a commit, the document has the missing attributes.

But my latest test did not complete the document after a edit/save, so this doesn't always seem to work.

Re-indexing (just) the catalogsearch does not seem to help either.

Running on Magento Enterprise 1.10.1.1 without additional plugins. Solr 3.4.0.

Comment: specify Magento version, solr extension and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I think your version of Magento is too old to handle Solr correctly. I ran into a similar issue when working with Solr 3.6.2 and Magento EE 1.12. Reindexing from the command line resulted in missing fields in the Solr search index. SKU and category_position_XX and some others where there, but all the dynamic fields were missing. Rebuilding the index from the backend is not an option for me as I'm dealing with +1.2 million SKUs.

I found some inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624068/magento-reindexing-loses-solr-docs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667728/magento-1-12-and-solr-3-6-no-proper-results-and-no-spell-suggestions).